# Where is Dart SDK? | Error: the folder specified as the Dart SDK home does not exists

Tags: intellij-idea, dart

I installed Dart Plugin in IntelliJ IDEA and set Dart SDK path in settings page and got this error message `Error: Dart SDK is not found in the specified location.` What path should I set here? Where is Dark SDK?

I went to this page:

https://dart.dev/get-dart#install

and I installed `dart` following **Install the Dart SDK** section.

> As the following instructions show, you can use a package manager to easily install and update the Dart SDK.

`dart` command is here: `/usr/local/bin/dart`.

but I cannot set this path as Dart SDK path in IntelliJ.

```
$ which dart
$ /usr/local/bin/dart
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot set this path as Dart SDK path in IntelliJ"? What happens if you set this path as `Dart SDK Path` in IntelliJ?

Comment: @Lesiak When I set dart path in IntelliJ, I got this message: `Error: the folder specified as the Dart SDK home does not exists`

Comment: And what value you set in IntelliJ? Note that `/usr/local/bin/dart` is most likely a symbolic link to another location. Use `ls -al /usr/local/bin/dart` to find out where the link points to.

Comment: You need to point to the location of Dart SDK and not the dart binary. If you installed the Debian package the location of the SDK should be: /usr/lib/dart/

Comment: @Lesiak Thank you, I got dart SDK path!

Comment: @Lesiak On MacOS, the symlink points to `/usr/local/Cellar/dart/2.7.2`. I tried `/usr/local/Cellar`, `/usr/local/Cellar/dart`, `/usr/local/Cellar/dart/2.7.2` and `/usr/local/Cellar/dart/2.7.2/bin` as the SDK path, but IntelliJ keeps claiming "Dart SDK is not found in the specified location". The dart command works just fine when used from the command line. Anything else I should try?

Comment: @Jorn I checked today on my Mac, indeed it was not noticing dart with IntelliJ 2020.1, but update of dart plugin helped (now using 201.6668.159)

Comment: @Lesiak Thanks for checking. I already have that version of the plugin (installed today), on IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.1, so I'm afraid that doesn't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

You can set the path this way in **Preferences > Languages & Framework > Dart** : **Dart SDK Path**

```
/usr/local/opt/dart/libexec
```

Or

```
/usr/local/Cellar/dart/2.8.3/libexec
```

not

```
/usr/local/bin/dart
```

I installed dart using Homebrew. I was able to get this path by running the command `brew info dart` but the above path should work for you as well

Comment: Greate ! `brew info dart`

Comment: This happens to me with /usr/local/opt/dart/libexec that brew info dart points to.

Answer (score 6):

navigate to the folder where you have kept your flutter folder and then just go to bin folder inside your flutter folder, and then to cache and here you go, you found dart sdk .location of dart sdk[dart sdk in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWzF7.png)
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache

Answer (score 5):

sometimes you add dart SDK with flutter SDK on developer folder if you using mac os ..

try this
/Users/username/developer/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk

Answer (score 1):

We should give the path for the 'dart-sdk' folder not the bin folder inside 'dart-sdk' folder.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62186444/10405867

yes, @Prateek Thakur answer is the best answer to be accepted.

To add the information.

- if you have installed from brew, mine using macbook m1 - apple silicon
  the default path is:
  /opt/homebrew/opt/dart/libexec/bin/dart
- if you are downloading from https://dart.dev/get-dart archive (link: https://dart.dev/get-dart/archive), you need to set the correct path on your local path where you downloaded the sdk archived folder.

Answer (score 0):

in manjaro if you installed from pamac(add/remove), then the command will be at

```
which dart
```

`/opt/flutter/bin/dart` 
So to solve this issue in intelliJ Idea..

Go to new project => dart => then in the Dart SDK path click on the ellipses

then locate this

```
/opt/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk
```